# Python + MIDI + Ableton Live, How?

Tags: android, python, midi, ableton-live

I write app with SL4A on Android. I want to send midi signals to Ableton Live. Tell me, HOW :> What library will be good for that ?

Comment: You need to be much more specific with what you are asking.  So, you want to use Python under SL4A on Android to get input from the Android device, send it over a network, which will then get turned into MIDI input to be handled by Ableton Live?  And what work have you done so far?  There is no single library for this.  First write the bit that handles the input. Then handle the network. Then on the PC you need to decide whether or not you are going to use one of the many existing network to MIDI protocols. Break this into chunks.  Do not ask for someone to write the whole thing for you.

Answer (score 4):

I would use OSC, rather an midi.

"Open Sound Control (OSC) is a protocol for communication among computers, sound synthesizers, and other multimedia devices that is optimized for modern networking technology. Bringing the benefits of modern networking technology to the world of electronic musical instruments, OSC's advantages include interoperability, accuracy, flexibility, and enhanced organization and documentation.

This simple yet powerful protocol provides everything needed for real-time control of sound and other media processing while remaining flexible and easy to implement."

http://opensoundcontrol.org/introduction-osc

OSC will let you deliver your data over ethernet (at a much finer granularity than the ancient 3kb/s venerable snail that is MIDI). You could then convert to MIDI with one of various OSC-MIDI interfaces.

http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/live-api

http://monome.q3f.org/wiki/LiveOSC

If you are very ambitious, you could use the unofficial Live Python API to control many aspects of LIVE itself. It's built for python, so you should feel at home. However, the project seems somewhat stale.

"FOR IMMEDIATE RELEASE:

CONTACT: LiveAPI.org Project

E-mail : press@liveapi.org

Website: http://www.liveapi.org/

LiveAPI.org Project Announces Third-Party Ableton Live API Python SDK

Santa Cruz, CA, USA, June 5th 2007 - LiveAPI.org is proud to announce the availability of the first SDK for Ableton Live's Python API.

LiveAPI.org is an independent open-source software development project with the aim of providing cutting-edge tools for manipulation of the Live Python API. Through reverse engineering and network programming techniques LiveAPI.org has created an SDK that will change the way you use of Ableton Live.

SDK components:

LiveOSC - A UDP network based Open Sound Control (OSC) interface that allows both sending and recieving of OSC messages through a Python callback system. Any task that can be performed with the Python API can be triggered as well as monitored. By Nathan Ramella and Rob King. Currently our updates are limited to 60ms intervals, but we hope to find ways to bring that number down. You won't be sending MIDI notes via OSC with a lot of success, but you can do so much more!

LiveTelnet - Telnet server access the Python CLI for exploration and programatical manipulation of the Live Python API. By Rob King

Ableton Live API Documentation - Full documentation on whats available in the Ableton Live Python API reprinted with permission from Ableton AG. Original extraction from runtime objects by James Andrew.

This announcement is to invite Ableton Live enthusiasts to visit LiveAPI.org, our source-code is free and released under the LGPL license, we have created a forum at http://www.LiveAPI.org/forum for discussion of LiveAPI.org based projects, SDK techniques and bug reports.

About LiveAPI.org - LiveAPI.org is an open-source project formed May 2007. LiveAPI.org SDK is the creation of Nathan Ramella, Rob King and James Andrew. For additional information visit us at http://www.LiveAPI.org, direct press inquiries to to press@liveapi.org."

http://forum.ableton.com/viewtopic.php?t=66118

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, sadly the LiveAPI site and code has been dead for quite a while now. If you look at the strings in the Live binary, you can clearly see python API bindings, but I believe they are only being used internally.